# smtp-sink not capturing mail on GitHub Actions

Tags: linux, email, smtp, github-actions

I'm trying to use [`smtp-sink`](http://www.postfix.org/smtp-sink.1.html) to capture mail sent by the [`mail`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mail) command (`mailx`).

This works fine on my work machine (RHEL7):

```sh
# Set the env variable `smtp`, which the `mail` command will use:
$ export smtp='localhost:8025'

# Set up the smtp-sink process listening on the port above:
$ smtp-sink -D 'mail_log.txt' -M 1 localhost:8025 1 &
# - will dump to mail_log.txt
# - "-M 1" makes it quit after receiving 1 email
# - the final "1" at the end is the backlog, doesn't matter too much
# - The "&" at the end sets the process up in the background

$ mail -s 'Test' <username> <<< 'This is a test'

$ cat mail_log.txt
X-Client-Addr: ipv6:::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx
X-Client-Proto: SMTP
...
Received: from <host> ([ipv6:::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx])
    by smtp-sink (smtp-sink) with SMTP id xxxxxxxx;
    Wed, 19 Aug 2020 11:51:51 +0100 (BST)
From: <username>@<host>
To: <username>
Subject: Test
Message-ID: <xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%<username>@<host>>
User-Agent: Heirloom mailx 12.5 7/5/10
...
This is a test
```

However, on GitHub Actions (Ubuntu) the email just bypasses `smtp-sink` and ends up in the mailbox. This is the workflow:

```yaml
jobs:
  test-smtp-sink:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y bsd-mailx

    - run: |
        export smtp='localhost:8025'
        smtp-sink -D 'mail_log.txt' -M 1 "$smtp" 1 &
        mail -s 'Test' runner <<< 'This is a test'

    - run: |
        mail # Checks mailbox - should be empty but instead contains the test email
        cat mail_log.txt # File doesn't exist
```

Why isn't SMTP capturing working on the GitHub Actions runner?

I also tried using Python's [`smtpd` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtpd.html) instead of `smtp-sink`:

```sh
$ python3 -u -m smtpd -c DebuggingServer -d -n "$smtp" &> mail_log.txt &
$ mail -s 'Test' runner <<< 'This is a test'
```

which again works on my local machine but on GH Actions the email bypasses that and ends up in the mailbox again.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer, but what we ended up doing instead was mocking the `mail` command using a python script (adding this script to `PATH`):

https://github.com/cylc/cylc-flow/blob/f97afc1231fe8e751ecfd52e0077f3a7cc4f356a/.github/bin/mail